# Upgraded from Eclipse RCP 3.x to 4.x: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

After upgrading my eclispe RCP from 3.x to 4.x I'm getting the following error on shutdown:

Note: I'm using the compatibility layer!

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:159)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4377)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDevice(Display.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.removeFilter(Display.java:4073)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.MenuManagerRenderer.contextDisposed(MenuManagerRenderer.java:338)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    ... 23 more
```

As you can see the only calls are within eclipse and not from my plugins. I'm pretty lost where to start looking to fix this issue. Since it also only appears on shutdown I have no idea if it is a problem for my application at all. I would really like to fix it. Advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Eclipse bug [436015](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436015).

The comments in the bug report say you need to include the `org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state` plugin in your RCP build